# what excel formulas can i use to return a MAX result from a Matrix when the Vlookup finds more than 1 result?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

here is a simplified table of my data

| ITEM | WEST | EAST |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ALPHA | 15 | 10 |
| ALPHA | 10 | 16 |

I am currently using a VLOOKUP with a MATCH formula to pull data, but it is of course only pulling the first match it finds.  here is a simplified version of the formula

```
=VLOOKUP("ALPHA",MATCH("WEST",$A$1:$C$1,0),FALSE)
```

I want to incorporate the MAX function or some other function into this formula so that when I look up item ALPHA for WEST region it returns 15 and for EAST region it returns 16.  the values are NOT able to be sorted so that the max in each region is always the first record.

Comment: You could research `MAXIFS`.

Comment: Yes I tried to incorporate MAXIFS to my formula and on its own, but I could not quite get the result I wanted.  very possible it is the solution but I just don't know how to implement it correctly for what I need

Comment: `AGGREGATE` works as well. `=AGGREGATE(14,6,B:B/(A:A="ALPHA"),1)`.  But you should avoid full column references.  MAXIFS is the superior function for this situation.

Answer (score 2):

Using `MAXIFS` and `INDEX`+`MATCH`:

```
=MAXIFS(INDEX(B:C,,MATCH("WEST",B1:C1,0)),A:A,"ALPHA")
```

[image]